# php ajax generate voucher

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

anyone know how to generate voucher code with ajax and php.
ive got the html form:

```
<form id="g_voucher" method="post">
      <h2>Generate Voucher</h2>
      <div class="v_code"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

ajax jquery???:

```
$('#g_voucher').submit(function(e){
  $.post('include/voucher.php?g_voucher', { },

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

for PHP will use simple code:

```
$v_code = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,999999)),0,10);
```

everytime i click submit button, it will keep generating new code..

Comment: @Pascal how to generate voucher code with ajax and php? :)

Comment: What kind of a voucher? For what? For a discount in an online transaction? Does the code have to be unique? Does the code have to be stored in a database? Please clarify what your question is about *exactly*.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the voucher in the session, and when generating a new voucher check if the session already contains a voucher.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['voucher'])) {
  return $_SESSION['voucher'];
}
```

Although this code will result in a new voucher each time the session is terminated (browser closed basically). To achieve a more permanent voucher, you should have some sort of client authentication + database to store the generated voucher.

Comment: Then do not use a session, instead store the information in the database in your users table. If a value exists in the table, retrieve it, if it doesn't, generate a new one.